# How to set image to top?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this html:

```
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="product1">
       <div class="card">
          <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center">
             <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/1f1a38/ffffff?text=Image">
             <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">Hello World</p>
                <p></p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I succesfully added the image and the text in the same line, but there is a problem: the image on the left appear to vertical center, I want vertical top, how can I do this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="product1">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center">
         <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/1f1a38/ffffff?text=Image">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Hello World. Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is at the vertical center because parent has class `align-items-center`. The easiest solution is to add `align-self-start` class to the image and it will be at the top.

You should check your code because `card-body` is inside `card-img-top`. Check the documentation here [LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/card/) and you will notice that `card-img-top` is mainy used to have image at the top of the card. Card body is usually placed directly inside card. What if you use media-object? Check out this [LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/media-object/)

By the way, there is a stable version of Bootstrap, latest is 4.2.1.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="product1">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top d-flex align-items-center">
         <img class="img-fluid align-self-start" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150/1f1a38/ffffff?text=Image">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Hello World. Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa. Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione. È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato. Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum</p>
            <p></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is also possible align the text on the same line of the image? If you look the text has an empty space on top

Comment: This space is padding from `card-body`

Comment: could you please answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491453/set-text-alignment-on-the-same-line-of-left-content